# why cant this delegate be passed to the base class constructor?

Tags: c#

```
class A<T>
{
    public A(Func<int, T> retriveFunc, Func<List<T>> loadFunc)
    {

    }
}

class Entity
{

}
class B : A<Entity>
{
    public B() : base(GetEntity,LoadEntities)
    {

    }

    private List<Entity> LoadEntities()
    {
        return new List<Entity>();
    }

    private Entity GetEntity(int serverID)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Why am i getting this error ?

> "Cannot access non-static method 'GetEntity' in static context"

Comment: You're trying to pass subclass members to your base class before your subclass has been constructed. That's dangerous and I'm happy that the compiler has made the right decision and bailed. Why not create virtual members in the base class and override them in the subclass, instead of trying to pass them down?

Comment: The way to get around this problem is to wrap those methods in lambda calls, something like `base(x => GetEntity(x),() => LoadEntities())`

Comment: @DavidArno .i like that !

Comment: That's pretty cool, but it still offers the possibility of danger if you decide to run the delegates in the base constructor. This is because the subclass portion of your object will not yet be initialized. Given the risk, I'd probably still opt for virtual members because they don't carry this hidden risk.